# Java Sort Two Text Files Alphabetically into one Text File

Tags: java, file, sorting

I need to take two text files and sort them alphabetically into one new created text file.

**greekWriters.txt contains:**

Aesop

Euripides

Homer

Plato

Socrates

**romanWriters.txt contains:**

Cicero

Livy

Ovid

Virgil

**This is my code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Driver {

public static void merge(String name1, String name2, String name3)
{
    File file1 = null, file2 = null, file3 = null;

    Scanner input1 = null, input2 = null;

    PrintWriter output = null;

    try {
        file1 = new File(name1);
        file2 = new File(name2);
        file3 = new File(name3);

        input1 = new Scanner(file1);
        input2 = new Scanner(file2);
        output = new PrintWriter(file3);
        String s1 = input1.nextLine();
        String s2 = input2.nextLine();


     // Problem Area
        while (input1.hasNext() && input2.hasNext())
        {
            if(s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) <= 0)
            {
                output.println(s1);
                s1 = input1.nextLine();
            }

            else 
            {
                output.println(s2);
                s2 = input2.nextLine();
            }
        }

    if (s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) <= 0)
    {
        output.println(s1 + "\n" + s2);
    }
    else 
    {
        output.println(s2 + "\n" + s1);
    }

    while (input1.hasNext())
    {
        output.println(input1.nextLine());
    }

    while (input2.hasNext())
    {
        output.println(input2.nextLine());
    }
    }

    // problem area end


    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in merge()\n" + e.getMessage());
    }

    finally
    {
        if (input1 != null)
        {
            input1.close();
        }
        if (input2 != null)
        {
            input2.close();
        }
        if (output != null)
        {
            output.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Finally block completed.");

    }


}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name1, name2, name3;

    name1 = "greekWriters.txt";

    name2 = "romanWriters.txt";

    System.out.print("Output File: ");
    name3 = input.next();
    merge(name1,name2,name3);
}

}
```

**This is the output:**

Aesop

Cicero

Euripides

Homer

Livy

Ovid

Plato

Virgil

Socrates

As you can see it is not in order (Virgil and Socrates), I believe the issue is by the while loop when the loop is reading the end of the text files in the compareToIgnoreCase methods. Please help me find the reason why it is not sorting correctly, I would like to sleep tonight. Thank you guys for your help in advance!

Comment: Will the input files always be sorted?  Might they be any size, or will they always be small?

Comment: The problem probably lies with this line                               if (s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) <= 0)         just by looking at it. I'll run some tests.

Comment: They should be sorted at any size, I kept it short just for example purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried this -

---

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      File inputfile1 = new File("C:/_mystuff/test.txt");
      File inputfile2 = new File("C:/_mystuff/test2.txt");

      Scanner readerL = new Scanner(inputfile1);
      Scanner readerR = new Scanner(inputfile2);

      String line1 = readerL.nextLine();
      String line2 = readerR.nextLine();
      while (line1 != null || line2 != null) {
        if (line1 == null) {
          System.out.println("from file2 >> " + line2);
          line2 = readLine(readerR);
        } else if (line2 == null) {
          System.out.println("from file1 >> " + line1);
          line1 = readLine(readerL);
        } else if (line1.compareToIgnoreCase(line2) <= 0) {
          System.out.println("from file1 >> " + line1);
          line1 = readLine(readerL);
        } else {
          System.out.println("from file2 >> " + line2);
          line2 = readLine(readerR);
        }
      }
      readerL.close();
      readerR.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public static String readLine(Scanner reader) {
    if (reader.hasNextLine())
      return reader.nextLine();
    else
      return null;
  }
```

---

Input:

File 1:

```
APPLES
CELERY
DONKEY
ZEBRA
```

File 2:

```
BANANA
FRUIT
NINJA
ORANGE
WASHINGTON
xmas
YATCH
```

Output:

```
from file1 >> APPLES
from file2 >> BANANA
from file1 >> CELERY
from file1 >> DONKEY
from file2 >> FRUIT
from file2 >> NINJA
from file2 >> ORANGE
from file2 >> WASHINGTON
from file2 >> xmas
from file2 >> YATCH
from file1 >> ZEBRA
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here's the issue: when you exit the

`while (input1.hasNext() && input2.hasNext())`

loop, s1 = "Plato" and s2 = "Virgil". You then move on the test of s1 and s2 and run:

`if (s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) <= 0)
{
    output.println(s1 + "\n" + s2);
}`

But the problem is that there are still tokens in file1 that are less than Virgil (namely "Socrates"). You can't assume that if s1 < s2 here that you can immediately output s2. There may be lots of names in s1 that are less than s2 - you have to keep looping through s1 until you find the first token >= s2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short & simple solution:

```
//read in both files
List<String> firstFileLines=Files.readAllLines(file1.toPath(),Charset.  defaultCharset());
List<String> secondFileLines=Files.readAllLines(file2.toPath(),Charset.     defaultCharset());

//put the lines of the two files together
ArrayList<String> allLines=new ArrayList<String>();
allLines.addAll(firstFileLines);
allLines.addAll(secondFileLines);

//sort (case insensitive & write out result
Collections.sort(allLines,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
File.writeAllLines(outFile.toPath(),allLines,Charset.defaultCharset());
```

I offered this solution instead of seeing what was wrong with yours because this can be more generic (easy to extend this to handle N-files or unsorted files) and sometimes a simpler solution is better than a faster solution. Please don't take offence, ignore this 'answer' as you please.